# Add Date to raster layers in raster stack in R

Tags: r, date, data-frame, rasterstack, addlayer

I have a raster stack and I want to add to it a Date field which will include the year-month-day for every rasterlayer. I have my dates in a one column data.frame. 
I tried to do this with `addLayer` but it didn't work.

Any ideas?

Example:

```
dt<-as.data.frame(as.Date(c('2010-11-1','2008-3-25','2007-3-14','2007-3-18','2007-3-20')))

ras = raster(matrix(1:30,3,4))
my_s = stack(ras,ras,ras,ras,ras)
my_s <- addLayer(my_s, dt)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding a layer doesn't make sense because you  are trying to associate a value with each layer, rather than creating a new NxM layer of values. Use `setZ` instead:

```
dt<-as.data.frame(
  as.Date(c('2010-11-1','2008-3-25','2007-3-14','2007-3-18','2007-3-20')))

ras = raster(matrix(1:30,3,4))
my_s = stack(ras,ras,ras,ras,ras)
my_s <- setZ(my_s, dt[,1], "SampleDate")
```

get the values back with `getZ` - they are still dates:

```
> getZ(my_s)
[1] "2010-11-01" "2008-03-25" "2007-03-14" "2007-03-18" "2007-03-20"
> class(getZ(my_s))
[1] "Date"
```

Comment: Thanks @Spacedman. That is what I was looking for.

Comment: One question though, in this way, if I change my raster stack in raster bric the z  are not prezerved. Is there a way to always preserve it within different calculations?

Comment: No, it seems you have to pass them on explicitly: `b = brick(s);setZ(b, getZ(s))` or maybe `b=brick(s); b@z = s@z` to copy the Z component of the object directly. Z's are "in development" according to the help(setZ).